# Redux state is not getting initialized to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux`. Here, I have a reducer which is like,

```
const initialState = {
    Low: [
        {
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 6,
            level: 'EASY'
        }
    ],
    Medium: [
        {
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'MEDIUM'
        }
    ],
    High: [
        {
            id: 0,
            technologyId: 0,
            technology: '',
            type: '',
            count: '',
            allowded: 7,
            level: 'TOUGH'
        }
    ]
}

export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) { 
   switch (action.type) {
        case QUIZ_DATA:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.data.type]: [...action.data.tobeData],
            error: false,
        }
    case ADD_NEW:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.data.addtype]: action.data.addData,
            error: false,
        }
    case REMOVE_TECH:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.data.removeType]: action.data.newArr,
            error: false,
        }
        case RESET_QUIZ:
            return {
                ...initialState,
                error: false,
            }

 }
```

Now, Here on click of button I am calling an action that will reset the data to initial state.

```
this.props.resetQuiz();
```

which is

```
export function resetQuiz() {
  return {
    type: RESET_QUIZ
  }
}
```

where I use it

let newData = { ...this.props.data }; while using it in the component to do some operation.

Now here what happens is after doing some actions the initial state data gets changes with some new values,..

But,on click of the button I want to set it like, initialState.

So, when I tried that time, that initialState is also getting the same values. So, It is not resetting.

I am using it in component like,

```
data: state.QuizData // In statetoprops.

let criterias = [{
      type: 'Low',
      noc: 6,
      id: 1,
      data: this.props.data["Low"]
    }, {
      type: 'Medium',
      noc: 7,
      id: 2,
      data: this.props.data["Medium"]

    },
    {
      type: 'High',
      noc: 7,
      id: 3,
      data: this.props.data["High"]
    }]
```

While using the action in component like,

```
createQuestionBankQuiz = () => {
    this.props.resetQuiz();
    history.push({
      pathname: "/quiz-setup/" + `${this.props.jdId}`
    });
  };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchListOfQuiz, updateQuestionViewMode, enableJob, resetQuiz })(LandingScreen);
```

The way I update is

```
onChange(event, tobeupdated, id, type, noc, data) {
    let newData = { ...this.props.data };
    let errorState;
    let isDuplicate;
    let addedRow;
    if (newData) {
      let data = newData[type].map((object, index) => {
        if (object.id === id) {
          object[tobeupdated] = event.target.value;
          const tobeData = newData[type];
          this.props.updateLowLevel({ tobeData, type }).then(() => {
            let criteria_filled = this.disableAddbutton({ ...this.props.data }, type);
            addedRow = `new${type}RowAdded`;
            this.setState({
              [addedRow]: criteria_filled ? true : false
            })
            const tobechecked = newData[type].filter(item => item.id === id);
            isDuplicate = this.checkPreviousSelected(newData, type, tobechecked[0].technology, tobechecked[0].type);
            if (isDuplicate) {
              toastr.error("Duplicate criteria. Please change it.");
              object["technology"] = '';
              object["type"] = '';
              const tobeData = newData[type];
              this.props.updateLowLevel({ tobeData, type });
            }
          });
        }
      });
      errorState = `show${type}Error`;
      if (tobeupdated !== "count") {
        this.getSelectionQuestionsNumber(type, id, noc);
      }
      let validateData = this.validate(type, noc);
      this.setState({
        [errorState]: validateData
      })
    }
  }
```

What is it that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why can't you just `return initialState` if you want to reset to that? I.e. `case RESET_QUIZ: return initialState;`

Comment: I tried this as well.

Comment: Clearly you are setting your quiz data somewhere else then. There is no way that your state doesn't get reset to `initialState` if you return `initialState` in your reducer. How are you dispatching the action?

Comment: Your code returns a new state instead of resetting `initialState`.So try code like`Object.assign(initialState,{a:somevalue})`.

Comment: @lx1412 That goes against the principle of `react-redux`.

Comment: @nbokmans,Yes.reducer should always be a pure function.

Comment: That's not what I was getting at. `initialState` is, as the name says, the initial state of a reducer. It should not be manipulated.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate I think issue with your action missing dispatch. please check in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrong with action dispatch

```
export function resetQuiz() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: RESET_QUIZ
    })
  }
}
```

I think better if you try with this in reducer

```
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET_QUIZ:
      return Object.assign({}, initialState, {error: false})

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried but it also giving me the same values.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate please try again with `return Object.assign({}, initialState, {error: false})` I edited.

Comment: I have just updated the way I am using other cases in the same reducer,

Comment: @ganeshkaspate I think you wrong in dispatch action. please try with action I edited.

Comment: Most likely a problem with how the action is dispatched indeed, nice catch

Comment: cool!. I have similar mistake with redux action when begin with React Redux.

Comment: Watch out here, if you're using the `resetQuizz` in the `mapDispatchToProps` property of the `connect` component, you're going to dispatch the `resetQuiz` functions, thus making it a `thunk`, so you would need a special middleware to handle this (`redux-thunk`). I think the original issue is just in the way the original action is dispatched.

Comment: @TungDuong Can you please see my updated code in question, the way I am updating the values in that object

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not doing deep copy in other actions.

Can you add the code of reducer for other actions?

Edit:
Quick solution for your problems is to change your reducer like below:

```
export default function QuizData(state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState)), action) { 
  ....
 }
```

Note: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState)) works for your case but not for all the cases, and not a good solution. You have to write deep copy logic for that.

**Correct/Proper solution**:

You have to modify your component logic to not modify store data directly and update it through other actions.

Comment: The way I am updating it is , also I have added.

Comment: In component where you added QuizData to criterias, will actually refer to the initialState inner object. So any modification to inner object will result in actual initialState object modification. (...state) will copy only first level properties. Can you add your component code where you are updating 'criterias' data?

Comment: object[tobeupdated] = event.target.value; here you are updating the existing object, instead you can do {...object, [tobeupdated]: event.target.value}

Comment: Here I do the let newData = { ...this.props.data };

Comment: Could you please add it in the answer so that I can check

Answer (score 0):

you just need to return the initial value in reducer, like this for example:

```
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESET_QUIZ:
      return initialState

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the `state` in your reducer for the `default` action :

```
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) { 
   switch (action.type) {
        case QUIZ_DATA:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.data.type]: [...action.data.tobeData],
            error: false,
        }
    case ADD_NEW:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.data.addtype]: action.data.addData,
            error: false,
        }
    case REMOVE_TECH:
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.data.removeType]: action.data.newArr,
            error: false,
        }
        case RESET_QUIZ:
            return {
                ...initialState,
                error: false,
            }

   return state; // you forgot this
 }
```

`redux` issues some kind of `init` action when the store is initialized, so you need to return the given `state` in your reducers for others actions than the ones you defined yourself.

Comment: I have the default :

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question, can you show us the code of your `connect` component ? I think you might have forgot to really dispatch the action.

Comment: export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchListOfQuiz, updateQuestionViewMode, enableJob, resetQuiz })(LandingScreen);

Comment: @ganeshkaspate you still have the problem to not returning the initial state by default in your reducer by the way

Comment: Not in the code you posted abode, the "default case" for the QuizData reducer is still missing

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Sill not good, I'm not talking about your "reset" action, you need to handle the case where the action given in your `QuizData`  function is not one of the actions your are handling